# The person who requests something is called...?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say that I have a collection of books, and someone requests one of them. How would that person would be called, in one word?

The only thing I have been able to come up is "pretender", but does not sound right, for some reason.

Comment: Requester? Suppliant?

Comment: By the example, I wonder if you're reaching for *patron*

Comment: "Requester" seems fine to me.

Comment: May I use two words?  **Would-be borrower**.

Comment: Sounds more like 3 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another option would be ***[applicant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/applicant)***.

> **noun**
>
> 1. a person who applies for or requests something; a candidate:
>    *an applicant for a position.*

Reference:
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/applicant

Comment: So far this is the one I like the most.

Answer (score 2):

"Requester" has the meaning your looking for.

Do note though that this is a word that most native English speakers would never use as we would instead say the likes of "The person requesting the books".

However, the word is easy for English speakers to understand and if you want a variable in your code to refer to such a person then "Requester" is the word to use in my opinion.

Comment: Is that a real word? I did not find it in any dictionary: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/requester

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/requester

Comment: Even though the search is for "Requester", the results shown are for "Request"

Comment: You will see that "Requester" is mentioned on the linked page as is a quote from Pride and Prejudice using the word.

Comment: @Dbugger - Even my browser's spell checker recognizes "requester".

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Baz's ***requester***, but if you don't feel comfortable with that, perhaps you can use ***[solicitor](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/solicitor?showCookiePolicy=true)***, ***[petitioner](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/petitioner?showCookiePolicy=true)*** or ***[supplicant](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/supplicant#supplicant_1)***

Answer (score 0):

A **requisitor** makes a requisiton, or a formal request.

[from Wiki](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/requisitor)

related: inquisitor, interrogator

Answer (score 0):

Begging is a form of request, practiced by a **beggar**.

Comment: Sounds a little demeaning, but I guess you are right.

Answer (score 0):

People go to public libraries and ask for books: aren't they *borrowers?*
Perhaps I've been reading too many history books.  They used to be called lending libraries, in the dim past.

***Borrower***  as in

> ***Borrower's card***  ([free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/borrower's+card)) Noun
>   1.    **borrower's card** - a card certifying the bearer's right to use the library.
>   library card

Comment: I didn't mean in the sense that the book will be given back.

Comment: Accent borrower with heavy irony then. And quote Polonius: " Neither a borrower nor a lender be; For loan oft ..."