# What do you call a person who requests a service?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I´ve been trying to get some answers on this topic [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269479/the-person-who-requests-something-is-called), [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/people-who-ask-or-answer-questions-or-make-requests), and other sources. I'd like to know a way to refer to a person who has made a request, but is not my actual customer/client.

Just to illustrate, picture this scenario:

> My client is the CEO of a company. A request has been made by his/her secretary, I still need to save his/her details to keep track of the service.

What would you call the secretary on this scenario? I'm aware the word "requestor" is not really used by native speakers, so how'd one call this person in a "not very long" way? (e.g. "person who has booked the service")

ps: i could use "Requested by:" but later i have to collect their contact info such as phone and email.

Comment: Maybe you could call her an "authorized individual"? Can you provide more details as to what she is? Is she authorized to make requests on his behalf? Why is there a need to name her?

Comment: Thanks Hank, please see my edited question for an update, anyone within the company could make a request so it's important to know who. the real client would be the company itself.

Comment: Where exactly will you be using the name? Do you want a name to describe the secretary or a name that describes any authorized member of the company that isn't the CEO?

Comment: i want to use it in a form that i'm creating, but i can´t use "authorized member" and then "Authorized member´s phone" and "Authorized member´s phone" and would also defeat the purpose of my question because it would make this answer way too specific, i don´t know if it makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't the secretary be just one of your client's *contacts*?

Comment: If I thought of this in a computer database way,  I would say you have a model called "person" (or 'user' or 'contact') .  A person could have relationships with other people related to their task.  A 'person' could have a "belongs to" relationship in a field "spouse" ... but the spouse is simply another 'person'.  Similarly a person could have a fields 'reportsTo' , and "assistantOf', but which would refer to other individual 'person'(s). (I don't think you want to get into a schema design, but if you were using a SQL type database you'd need  join tables to keep track of that, but thats ok).

Comment: You could just say *secretary*. But I suppose one day its a secretary, the next it is the handyman, the next the book-keeper etc. I suppose you could say *factotum*.

Answer (score 3):

The person is acting as an [**agent**](https://www.google.com/search?q=agent%20defintion):

> 1.
>   a person who acts on behalf of another person or group.

(GOOG)

Answer (score 0):

That person who made a request on behalf of someone else is a ***proxy/representative***.

ODO:

> **[proxy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/proxy)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.1**[count noun] A person authorized to act on behalf of another.
>
> ‘The letter was handed over by Peter Brown, himself an accountant and
>   auditor, who was attending the meeting as a proxy on behalf of a
>   shareholder.’
>
> **[representative](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/representative)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A person chosen or appointed to act or speak for another or others
>
> ‘Grosso asked to speak to the GMAC representatives alone.’